# Dynamically show another graph within a node in Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm using Cytoscape.js to visualize a large, nested data structure. Showing the whole graph directly makes it hard to interpret, so I'm only showing the top-level nodes at first. Then, when a node is clicked, I want to show the subgraph *within* the node.

My first attempt was to just add the subgraph as child nodes. The child nodes initially have `visibility: hidden`, but are shown once their parent node has been selected (the parent node itself also changes its appearance a bit when this happens, to indicate it has received the focus). This works, somewhat. However, the top-level nodes are drawn very large, obviously since they now contain their hidden child nodes.

So my alternative solution would be to dynamically add the child nodes at the moment when their parent receives focus. However, this would probably require some additional restrictions on Cytoscape, as I don't want the parent node to grow or move when this happens. So basically the node bounds of the parent becomes the canvas in which the child graph should be drawn.

My double questions is then (1) whether Cytoscape can actually introduce such constraints, and (2) if this is really the best solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse ?

Comment: @Ravenous Thanks for that! I had actually stumbled on their GitHub page, but I initially dismissed it because of the animated GIF (which doesn't do a great job of showcasing their ideas). After checking out the demos it's indeed very useful and close to what I want. The only downside is that the rest of the graph moves about a bit when expanding a node, while ideally I would want everything to remain stable and have the nested graph expand *within* the parent node. But still, this is very useful!